# How does facebook generate image names?

Tags: php, mysql, random

I guess it is a concatenation of the user ID and a random number but how does facebook ensure that no two photos have the same name?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but an easy way would be to combine the user ID with a time string.

Comment: User Id + time() + random number makes a great name. It's not nearly possible that there is another file with this name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how facebook does it, but you are certainly on the right track with your user ID and random number (using a PHP function like uniqid()). You could throw the MD5 of the image in there for good measure. You are right in assuming that you are still at risk of having a name collision even with the most random scheme. You add overhead to your application to check for this, but the way you could do it is like this.  Note, this assumes your a using physical file system and not tracking files in a DB and storing them on a cloud solution

```
function ensure_unique_filepath($path){
  $incr = 1;
  while(file_exists($path)){
    $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
    $path = $path_parts['dirname'] . '/' . $path_parts['filename'] .  '_' . $incr . '.' . $path_parts['extension'];
  }
  return $path;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function **StrongFileName()** will generate a strong file_name. The file name thus generated is the combination of :

> User ID + time() + Random Number

and the whole code is :

```
function random_number($length) {
 $chars = "0123456789011121314151617181920"; 
 $size = strlen( $chars );
 for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++) {
  $str.=$chars[rand(0,$size-1)];
 }
 return $str;
}
function StrongFileName($user){
 $time=time();
 $random=random_number(10);
 $filename=$user."_".$time."_".$random;
 return $filename;
}
```

Usage :

```
echo StrongFileName("1002548");
```